# Select multiple rows with (repeat until certain amount) one by one in shop bundling system using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

So I'm new to MySQL, and I'm making a system for buying in-game items in bundles for my college game project.

So far I have a shop table for displaying the items that are available in the in-game store

```
CREATE TABLE t_shop(
    shop_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_type_id INT,
    item_id INT,
    amount INT,
    price INT,
);
```

(Bundle items has null values in item_type_id, item_id, and amount which will be useful later as a mark that it's a bundle item in my buy item procedure)

And a bundle table with the details of what items are contained within that bundle (with shop_id as a foreign key that points which bundle it belong to in the shop table)

```
CREATE TABLE t_special_box(
    shop_id INT,
    item_type_id INT,
    item_id INT,
    amount INT,
    
    CONSTRAINT FK_t_special_box_shop_id
    FOREIGN KEY (shop_id) REFERENCES
    t_shop(shop_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

In my stored procedure, I want to insert the items within the "t_special_box" table into each of my inventory tables when it detects the shop_id as a bundle table (item_type_id will be used to determine "which inventory the item belongs to" for inserting in the stored procedure)

So far this is what I got

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p_special_box_calculate(in v_player_id INT, in v_shop_id INT)
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
this_proc: BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT COUNT(shop_id)
    INTO @counter
    FROM t_special_box
    WHERE shop_id = v_shop_id;
    
    REPEAT
        SELECT item_type_id, item_id, amount
        INTO @item_type_id, @item_id, @amount
        FROM t_special_box
        WHERE shop_id = v_shop_id
        LIMIT 1;
        
        CALL p_item_insert(v_player_id, @item_type_id, @item_id, @amount);
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    UNTIL counter = @counter
    END REPEAT;
    
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Say in my t_special_box table there are:

```
shop_id, item_type_id, item_id, amount:
(10, 2, 3, 30)
(10, 1, 3, 2)
```

The problem with the "p_special_box_calculate" procedure is, it can only read the first row which is the (10, 2, 3, 30), and it's inserted twice while ignoring the rest of the rows.

I want my procedure to read both rows one by one, so then it can then run the "p_item_insert" procedure with each selected rows (that have the same shop_id of course), and then each data that is selected will be inserted to each inventory tables it's assigned to

PS: I'm trying to give out as much information as I can with my limited knowledge, so if you need any more details, please don't hesitate to ask or correct me :)

Comment: I admit, I don't really understand it, but it *feels* like an xy problem

Comment: I don't think that's the case, but then again, I could be wrong. Of all stored procedures that I'm currently working on, this is so far the only one that I haven't figure out yet. I'm also fairly new with MySQL and I don't have anyone to guide me atm, but I still have to get this project done :(

Edit: if you do have another solution in your mind, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

It turns out it's just as simple as adding `OFFSET counter` before `LIMIT 1` inside the repeat statement, so it can select the next row according to counter that I declared before (which adds itself by one every time until it meets its required amount)

So here's the final solution:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p_special_box_calculate;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p_special_box_calculate(in v_player_id INT, in v_shop_id INT, out result INT)
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
this_proc: BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT COUNT(shop_id)
    INTO @counter
    FROM t_special_box_detail
    WHERE shop_id = v_shop_id;
    
    REPEAT
        SELECT item_type_id, item_id, amount
        INTO @item_type_id, @item_id, @amount
        FROM t_special_box_detail
        WHERE shop_id = v_shop_id
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET counter;

        CALL p_inventory_item_insert(v_player_id, @item_type_id, @item_id, @amount, @result);
        
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    UNTIL counter = @counter
    END REPEAT;
    
    SET result = 1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I feel so dumb right now lol